# Enum evaluation in c#

Tags: c#, enums, casting

Say I have enum as follows (taken from MSDN example):

```
enum Days {Sat=1, Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri};
```

I can then use is in the code as follows:

```
int today = (int)Days.Sun;
```

Question:

Can I evaluate enums? Say I have a variable Day whose value is "Sun". 
Will Days.Day evaluate to Days.Sun?

Thanks!

Please don't get hung up on the days example and tell me I should use comparison etc...i am looking to replace the usage of arrays with enums as it is more compact. So what I am looking for is essentially an ability to retrieve values from enum similar to an array:

myArray[Day] where day will evaluate to array key....

Comment: Methinks a quick test would have answered the question for you in less time than it took to write this question.

Comment: i disagree, but thanks for valuable input:)

Comment: @gnoxima: My mistake, actually. I thought you were simply talking about casting. Indeed, the Enum.Parse method isn't so apparent.

Comment: no worries. i did a google search first but unfortunately didn't know what to look for - should have looked for Parse; so my search didn't come up with anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Am I right in saying you've got:

```
string day = "Sun";
```

and you want to get back the value `Days.Sun`?

If so, use:

```
string day = "Sun";
Day day = (Day) Enum.Parse(typeof(Days), day);
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do that.  You can freely cast between an `enum` and its underlying type.

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // prints "zero"
        Console.WriteLine((Foo)0);
        // prints "1"
        Console.WriteLine((int)Foo.one);
    }
}

enum Foo { zero, one, two };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also parse the string values as well. Using `Enum.Parse`

```
[TestFixture]
public class EnumParsingSO
{
    public enum Days
    {
        Sat = 1,
        Sun,
        Mon,
        Tues
    }

    [Test]
    public void EnumFromString()
    {
        Days expected = Days.Mon;
        int expectedInt = 3;
        Days actual = (Days)Enum.Parse(typeof(Days), "Mon");

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedInt, (int)actual);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Andrew says, you can cast from an enum to its underlying type. You can also unbox between the two as well, and there's an implicit conversion from the constant 0 to any enum type:

```
using System;

enum Demo { Foo, Bar, Baz };

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int i = 2;
        object o = i;
        // Unboxing from int to Demo
        Demo d = (Demo) o;
        Console.WriteLine(d);

        o = Demo.Baz;
        // Unboxing from Demo to int
        i = (int) o;
        Console.WriteLine(i);

        // Implicit conversion of 0
        d = 0;
        Console.WriteLine(d);
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is simpler than that I believe. His day variable is already of the enum type.

Answer (score 0):

for int yes , but for string you should do something like [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/stefansedich/archive/2008/03/12/enum-with-string-values-in-c.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you just need to provide the native integer value for each enum value.  From your example:

```
enum Days {
    Sat=1, 
    Sun=2, 
    Mon=3, 
    Tue=4, 
    Wed=5, 
    Thu=6, 
    Fri=7
};
```

(Now, why you would order days of the week in this way is beyond me...)

Comment: Although I agree that you /should/ assign numbers to each value, it is not required.

Comment: guys! its just an example! :)